# Get newest child on parent.all in one call - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parent-child

I have 2 models, `orders` and `order_status_details`. The last is just a history of status changes for each order.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_status_details, :dependent => :destroy
end

class OrderStatusDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order, foreign_key: :order_id
end
```

Im getting all the orders with this:

```
@orders = Order.all.order('id DESC')
```

Now, I want to include the newest status. For example:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | status_id | created_at          | updated_at          | order_id |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 |         1 | 2016-01-31 04:00:00 | 2016-01-31 04:00:00 |        7 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|  2 |         3 | 2016-01-31 05:00:00 | 2016-01-31 05:00:00 |        7 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|  3 |         5 | 2016-01-31 06:00:00 | 2016-01-31 06:00:00 |        7 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

The correct must be row #3, status #5.

Check my schema.rb:

```
  create_table "order_status_details", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "status_id",  limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.integer  "order_id",   limit: 4
  end

  create_table "order_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.boolean  "paid"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id", limit: 4
    t.decimal  "subtotal",                precision: 10
    t.decimal  "tax",                     precision: 10
    t.decimal  "total",                   precision: 10
    t.integer  "invoice",     limit: 4
    t.integer  "shipping_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.decimal  "comission",               precision: 10
    t.string   "comment",     limit: 255
  end
```

How can in one call?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `scope`? Do you want to fetch *only* the newest status from the database, or fetch all of them and show the newest one in a special way?

Comment: One more correction. you don't need to mentioned explicitly the foreign key in your case. It will work 100% with `belongs_to :order`.

Comment: Forget the scope, the correct is Order model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the query as:

```
Order
 .joins(order_status_details: :order_status)
 .order('id DESC')
 .where(
    "order_status_details.status_id = \
     (SELECT max(status_id) FROM order_status_details)"
  )
 .select("orders.*, order_statuses.name")
```

Comment: Sorry about this, the scope is Order model... is not related with status. Check the update please

Comment: Sorry but Im still seeing the same :/

Comment: @AlejandroAraujo I had a typo, now please check.

Comment: Im gettin this error bro:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'status_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` WHERE (status_id = max(status_id))

The table above is order_status_details, not orders :(

Comment: @AlejandroAraujo please include the schema.rb content for the 2 models.

Comment: Done, please the schema.

It can't be OrderStatusDetails because I need a Orders list (All) with the most recent status inside.

Comment: Something like:

Order.all.order('id DESC')
OrderStatusDetail.order('created_at DESC').limit(1).first

combined, need more details? Please let me know